# Button on drawn object

Tags: c#, silverlight, xna

I'm trying to add a button so that it will appear on top of a screen that I'm drawing, in an XNA/Silverlight Windows phone game.

Currently the map is drawing over it, so the button appears invisible. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

The Button `switchScreen` is created, but not initialized, earlier in the code.

Here is the code where I'm adding the button:

```
private void OnDraw(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
{
    #region CommonStuff
    SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    #endregion CommonStuff
    if (is3D)
    {
        OnDraw3D(sender, e);
    }
    else
    {
        OnDraw2D(sender, e);
    }
    switchScreen = new Button();
    switchScreen.Height = 20.0;
    switchScreen.Width = 100.0;
    switchScreen.Content = "Switch to Shooting Screen";
    switchScreen.Margin = new Thickness(phoneScreen.Height - switchScreen.Width - 
        20.0, 20.0, 20.0, phoneScreen.Width - switchScreen.Height - 20.0);
    switchScreen.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

I'm only testing the `OnDraw2D` so here's the code for that:

```
private void OnDraw2D(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    // TODO: Add your drawing code here
    map.Draw(e.ElapsedTime, e.TotalTime);

    // npc.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

and the `map.Draw` is here

```
public override void Draw(TimeSpan elapsedTime, TimeSpan totalTime)
{
    // Draw the Sky
    gamePage.getSpriteBatch().Draw(background, Position, Color.White);

    foreach (Person person in people)
    {
        person.Draw(elapsedTime, totalTime);
    }

    base.Draw(elapsedTime, totalTime);
}
```

`background` is a `Texture.2D` and `Position` is a `Vector2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, since you're creating the button manually, you may need to use this code instead (I am assuming that you're using the Windows Forms `Button` control):

```
switchScreen.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(xLocation, yLocation);
switchScreen.Name = name;
switchScreen.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(xSize, ySize);
switchScreen.TabIndex = 0;
switchScreen.Text = text;
switchScreen.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

Controls.Add(switchScreen);
```

How are you implementing a Windows Form? As far as I know, you can't add a Button without an underlying form for it to be on.